# WINDOWS-31J equivlent encoding in Linux

Tags: java

I'm wondering whether the following code will work in Linux.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream(),"WINDOWS-31J");
```

If not kindly point me to the direction which I can use the `WINDOWS-31J` equivalent of Linux character encoding.

Thanks in advance for any kind help.

Comment: You could possibly implement your own InputStream(Reader) that does the decoding.  It looks pretty easy to implement based on this table: http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP932.TXT

Comment: Try it and see. Are you sure if the file you're reading is actually going to be encoded in Windows-31J encoding, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `windows-31j` / `MS932` is shipped with the Oracle version of Java 7 for Solaris, Linux, and Windows. See [Supported Encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) for full list.

Answer (score 2):

According to Oracle docs, it is supported:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

```
Canonical Name for java.nio API  |  Canonical Name for java.io API and java.lang API | Description 
windows-31j                         MS932                                              Windows Japanese
```

So that you'd invoke it as:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream(),"MS932");
```

It mentions the charset is defined in the extended set: `lib/charsets.jar`.  You probably have to include that in your project.  It's in your JDK directory under jre\lib\charsets.jar.

Comment: You don't have to add `charsets.jar`. It's automatically included.